# Flatten RGB image array

Tags: arrays, rgb, flatten

I have 129756 RGB images (100X187) which I want to convert to an (m, n) array.

I used this code:

```
for i in range(len(imlist)):
 img =np.array(Image.open('/home/fatmasaid/new_flicker_data_resized_color'+'//'+imlist[i]))
 immatrix =np.array(img.flatten()) 
print (immatrix.shape )
```

I got (56100,)

However, I require an array with these dimensions: (129756, 56100)

How can I achieve that?

I also tried this code:

```
immatrix = np.empty((len(imlist),3, 187, 100), dtype="float32")
l=len(imlist)

for i in range(l):
    img = Image.open(path2 + '/'+ imlist[i])
    width, height=img.size


    r=np.zeros((187,100),dtype=float)
    g=np.zeros((187,100),dtype=float)
    b=np.zeros((187,100),dtype=float)

    for y in range(height-1):
        for x in range(width-1):
            rgb = img.getpixel((x,y))

            rgb=(rgb[0],rgb[1],rgb[2],);

            r[y][x]=rgb[0]
            g[y][x]=rgb[1]
            b[y][x]=rgb[2]

    AImg=[r,g,b]

    arr = np.asarray(AImg, dtype="float32")
    immatrix[i, :, :, :] = arr

    if i % 5000 == 0:
        print (i)
print (immatrix.shape)
```

but I got this error:

index 100 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 100

Comment: I assume you do realise this is going to need 28GB of RAM ?

Answer (score 0):

```
batch_array = np.empty([0])
for i in range(len(imlist)): 
    img = np.array(Image.open('/home/fatmasaid/new_flicker_data_resized_color'+'//'+imlist[i])) 
    immatrix =np.array(img.flatten())   
    batch_array = np.append(batch_array, immatrix) 
print (immatrix.shape )
```

You can try to append the immatrix to another array. Currently you are refreshing immatrix in every iteration of loop

Another way would be:

```
batch_array = np.empty([0])
for i in range(len(imlist)): 
    img = np.array(Image.open('/home/fatmasaid/new_flicker_data_resized_color'+'//'+imlist[i])) 

    batch_array = np.append(batch_array, img)

batch_array = batch_array.flatten()

batch_array = np.reshape(batch_array, (len(imlist), len(batch_array)/len(imlist)))
print (immatrix.shape )
```